# sklearn prediction error? output clarification

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hello I am attempting to do my first machine learning prediction and I want to test what the prediction should be. I am unsure if I should get an exact value when working with continuous data or an approximation was trying to use RM 6.575, LSTAT_LOG 1.7887421 to predict Median_Log 3.218876 but the prediction returned 3.4722003863374895.  Thanks

```
features.head()
      RM    LSTAT_LOG   Median_Log
0   6.575   1.788421    3.218876
1   6.421   2.316488    3.117950
2   7.185   1.615420    3.575151
3   6.998   1.371181    3.538057
4   7.147   1.845300    3.616309

Y = features.drop(['RM','LSTAT_LOG'],axis=1)
X = features.drop('Median_Log',axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1)

regression_model = LinearRegression()
rm = regression_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

int = rm.intercept_[0]
b = rm.coef_[0][0]


#Using features3.iloc[0:1,0:2] (6.575,1.788421) values to predict target of 
#features3.iloc[0:1,2:3] (3.218876)

prediction = rm.predict([[6.575,1.788421]])
predicted_value = prediction[0][0]
print(predicted_value)

3.4722003863374895
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with the prediction you got? Do you think it's too inaccurate or what?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

1. Is Median_Log correlated with each of the input columns?
2. Are the values of an input column correlated in a linear way?

You can use the following code if you want to check this:

```
from mlxtend.plotting import scatterplotmatrix
cols = ['RM', 'LSTAT_LOG', 'Median_Log']
scatterplotmatrix(features[cols].values, figsize=(10, 8), names=cols, alpha=0.5)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


import numpy as np
from mlxtend.plotting import heatmap
cm = np.corrcoef(features[cols].values.T)
hm = heatmap(cm, row_names=cols, column_names=cols)
plt.show()
```

[image: Check Linear regression]

In the first diagram you see for example that can expect (from your first 5 data points) that RM and Median log have linear relationship. In the second diagram you can see by looking for values near -1 and 1 if the variables have a dependencies.

You code is working, but you need to analysis your data to see if LinearRegression is possible.